# Why the cropped raster tiff generated from gdal_tranlaste is uncompressed and of very big size?

Tags: gdal

I am cropping a tif image file using gdal_translate but the resulting file is of bigger size compared to the original file.[image]

Here is the sample command that I am using to crop the image

```
gdal_translate -srcwin 4000 4500 2000 3000 Ortho.tif Ortho_cropped.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compress the output too with the following

```
gdal_translate -srcwin 4000 4500 2000 3000 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 Ortho.tif Ortho_cropped.tif
```

This uses deflate compression which is often quite effective. A predictor of 2 is often nice for integer values, while you can change the predictor to 3 if your values are floats.

You can use other compressions too like `ZSTD` if you are using gdal >= 2.3 which should be faster and archive similar compression rates. If you do not care about lossy compression, you can even use `JPEG`.

If you do not know the compression of your original image you can see what it is using the command  `gdalinfo Ortho.tif` where the compression is described under Image Structure Metadata